# Facebook FQL "PLACE" query returning very few results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have an FQL query set up to pull data from the "place" table:

```
select distance (latitude, longitude, "25.7877" , "-80.2241"), name from place 
  where (distance (latitude, longitude, "25.7877" , "-80.2241")<10000)
```

But it only returns 15 results.

If I change the distance from `<10000` to `<2000` I still get 15 results, a slightly different set.

I tried using a `limit`, but makes no difference.

In graph, a similar query using the distance returns few results...

```
search?type=place&center=37.76%2C-122.427&distance=5000%20&limit=500
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a bug report into Facebook.  Here's their response:

**Status has changed: Reopened → By Design**

> Sorry, at this time FQL cannot support what you're trying to do. The
>   only option available to find business near you is the "search" API,
>   where you can execute queries in the following format to get more
>   accurate results:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=pizza&type=place&center=25.7877,-80.2241&distance=1000
>   However, the caveat is you have to know what types of business you are
>   searching for to get relevant results, otherwise you run into the same
>   limitations you experienced with FQL.

The graph search is rather limited in it's capabilities, so if you were wanting to get a lot of info from the `place FQL table`, you'll need to get very creative and use several nested queries.